# React conditionally apply color to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to apply a color to a div conditionally based on 4 conditions. I usually use the ternary operator in the className prop but there is 4 conditions and there has got to be a better way to do this.

For example ,

```
<div className={`${styles.card} ${items.length > 1 && styles.blue} ${items.length > 2 && styles.green}` etc...}>data</div>
```

I cant use any other libraries either its just got to be using react

Answer (score 1):

You could build an array up with classes conditionally:

```
const Card = () => {
  const classNames = [styles.card];
  if (items.length === 1) {
    classNames.push(styles.blue);
  } else if (items.length > 1) {
    classNames.push(styles.green);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classNames.join(' ')}>data</div>
  )
};
```

Edit: Modified conditions to make more sense.

Comment: I like this way of doing it. Would there be any drawbacks if the component gets re rendered. Like the Card component has a items prop and if that changes then the if statements would re compute right?

Comment: @ousmane784 it would recompute and the `className` would be up-to-date. And if you're worrying about performance: it's negligible computation.

Comment: @dean It looks like the conditions are different than the ones in OP's question. If there are 3 items, it should have all three classes, not just `card` and `green`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `classcat` package. For me is the best approach to combine multiple class names based on different conditions.

```
import cc from "classcat";

<div
     className={cc([
       {
         [styles.card]: true,
         [styles.blue]: items.length > 1,
         [styles.green]: items.length > 2,
       },
     ])}
>
   data
</div>
```

Comment: I want to try to avoid using third party libraries at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a method that return the styles

```
const Card = () => {
   const handleStyles = () => {
      const classNames = [styles.card];
      if (items.length === 1) {
        classNames.push(styles.blue);
      }
      else if (items.length > 1) {
        classNames.push(styles.green);
      }

      return classNames.join('');
   }


  return (
    <div className={handleStyles}>data</div>
  )
};
```